# dnf: How to tell what's causing broken dependencies?

Tags: fedora, dependencies, dnf

Sometimes when doing a `dnf upgrade` I'll be told that it's skipping packages because of broken dependencies.  It will tell me which packages are being skipped, but not *why* they're being skipped.  How do I found out the "why"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the rather non-obvious `--best` option.  From the [man page](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html):

```
   -b, --best
          Try the best available package versions in transactions. Specif‐
          ically during dnf upgrade, which by default skips  over  updates
          that  can  not  be  installed for dependency reasons, the switch
          forces DNF to only consider the latest  packages.  When  running
          into  packages  with broken dependencies, DNF will fail giving a
          reason why the latest version can not be installed.
```