# Reverse dependencies to determining the Cause of DNF conflicting packages

Tags: fedora, package-management, dependencies, dnf

I recently tried to update some packages on my (fedora 27, x64) machine, which `dnf` complains is in conflict. However, I cannot figure out how to get `dnf` to tell me the cause of the conflict.[This related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/341333/) says that I should use `--best` to *solve* the problem, but this still doesn't tell me *why* a seemingly non-conflicting situation is considered a conflict.

The TL;DR of this question is: **how do I get `dnf` to tell me which packages are conflicting and what the associated dependents are?**

The following is the conflict:

```
$dnf update
Last metadata expiration check: 1:49:45 ago on Tue 27 Nov 2018 03:16:34 PM CET.
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem: problem with installed package i3status-2.12-1.fc27.x86_64
  - package i3status-2.12-1.fc27.x86_64 requires libconfuse.so.1()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libconfuse-3.2.2-1.fc27.x86_64 and libconfuse-3.2-3.fc27.x86_64
  - cannot install both libconfuse-3.2-3.fc27.x86_64 and libconfuse-3.2.2-1.fc27.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libconfuse-3.2-3.fc27.x86_64
```

I figured out (with `dnf --deplist info`) that `i3status-2.12-1.fc27.x86_64` depends on `libconfuse-3.2-3.fc27.x86_64`:

```
  dependency: libconfuse.so.1()(64bit)
   provider: libconfuse-3.2-3.fc27.x86_64
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out what thing depends on the older `libconfuse-3.2.2-1.fc27.x86_64` package. I assumed reverse dependencies of installed packages would be easy to search, but the solution suggested [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/117569/how-to-use-rpm-to-list-dependent-packages/) states that `dnf repoquery --available --alldeps --source --whatrequires libconfuse-3.2.2-1.fc27.x86_64` should do the trick; however the output is:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:59:58 ago on Tue 27 Nov 2018 03:16:34 PM CET.
libconfuse-3.2.2-1.fc27.src.rpm
```

And of that rpm, there are no dependencies at all. In other words, the only package that requires this is the package itself, but this doesn't happen all the time, so I'm guessing this list is somehow incomplete. Digging into `dnf repoquery` a bit, I found that `dnf repoquery --all --installed --whatrequires libconfuse` should give me the desired output. This says:

```
i3status-0:2.12-1.fc27.x86_64
```

Which is the package that was originally listed as the package I want to update, yet as already pointed out above, this depends on `libconfuse.so.1()(64bit)` provided by `libconfuse-3.2-3.fc27.x86_64`. In other words, there should be no conflict, according to this output. What am I missing here?

Comment: You probably need to file a bug report,  however fedora 27 is almost at EOL so perhaps best to upgrade to 28 or 29

Comment: @Panther I thought an update would have similar issues, so I figured it best to fix this and upgrade afterwards. In general, to whom should I file the bug report in a case like this? I don't feel that I understand whether the cause is a bug in `dnf`, an error in the `i3status` package dependencies, in the `libconfuse` package specification, or in my understanding of how `dnf` handles dependencies (I assumed the last of these was the issue).

Comment: Libconfuse I would think. They will close it when 27 goes eol in a few days so file it fast .... 3 or 4 days max

Answer (score 2):

The following command will return a list of the **installed** packages that depend on ***libconfuse*** and the exact version and architecture they depend on:

```bsh
sudo dnf repoquery --whatdepends libconfuse \
--queryformat "%{name}.%{arch} %{version}-%{release}" 2>/dev/null \
| grep -F -f <(sudo dnf list installed \
| tr -s '[[:space:]]' | cut -d ' ' -f-2) \
| xargs -L1 sudo dnf repoquery --deplist 2>/dev/null \
| grep 'package\|libconfuse'
```

(Make sure to replace **both** appearances of ***libconfuse*** with the library name dnf has the conflict with without any version number, otherwise it won't work)